# Opengl es 2.0 null pointer from findViewByID

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to set up an application using OpenGL ES 2.0, using the following tutorial:
http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-open-gl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-1/

So I was able to successfuly compile the application and run it in an emulator, but as soon as it launches, the app crashes... I have only 2 layout files:
activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.openglproject1.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

and fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gamelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

From my investigation it turned out that:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gamelayout);
```

in the OnCreate MainActivity's method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Turn off the window's title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Super
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Fullscreen mode
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // We create our Surfaceview for our OpenGL here.
        glSurfaceView = new GLSurf(this);

        // Set our view.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Retrieve our Relative layout from our main layout we just set to our view.
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gamelayout);

        // Attach our surfaceview to our relative layout from our main layout.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams glParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.addView(glSurfaceView, glParams);
    }
```

returns a null pointer... The whole code I used is presented in the link above but if you wish I can also paste it here, though it's big a bit. I'm just wondering if I need any additional file for the gamelayout or anything?... It's all very confusing for me so please don't hesitate to offer any tips! I would be very grateful for help!

Comment: There is nothing in your activity_main which refers to R.id.gamelayout. The said layout is inside of your fragment_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

You set your activity layout to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

The source for which is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.openglproject1.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

However you try to access `R.id.gamelayout` in the activity, however the said layout is specified in your  fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gamelayout"             //OVER HERE
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

So clearly the error lies in here.

Change this line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);` and let me know if it works?

Comment: I already tried to replace the content of activity_main with the fragment_main or adding the code from fragment_main to activity_main etc... but all in vain. Actually I don't understand why I get 2 layouts by creating an activity when in tutorials I always used only fragment_main.xml to add some Views like buttons etc... I'm still not quite sure how to solve that :/

Comment: You dont have to replace/ remove.. just reference what you specify in the layout tied to your activity. If that view is in your layout well and good, if not, you will get a NPE.

Comment: If I change only this one line, the problem persists. But if I change the content to fragment_main before the findViewById and set it back to activity_main after it then the application doesn't crash eventually. But is that the correct approach?

Comment: Actually the app doesn't draw a triangle as supposed so I guess there's still something wrong